# Running on an i3-6100U in an HP Pavillon with switchable graphics

Tags: i915, switchable-graphics, amd-graphics

I'm trying to see how well I can get Kubuntu 14.04 to run on my wife's HP Pavillon with its i3-6100U CPU and additiona Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265] (rev 81) discrete graphics.

It runs OK enough with the provided generic Xenial LT kernel (4.4.0.18 at the moment, I think), even from an external HDD in a USB3 enclosure (actually the internal disk fro the previous laptop). Yesterday I built the 4.5.2 kernel in order to be certain to have the latest drivers. I activated i915 preliminary hw support by default, but my grub.cfg also has

```
nmi_watchdog=0 i915.preliminary_hw_support=1  nomdmonddf nomdmonisw
```

Using the WL driver for the Broadcom WIFI chipset that clearly works a bit better even, but an issue remains with the graphics. I'm trying to use the CPU's integrated HD520 graphics but ATM all I succeed in getting is basic support for the AMD graphics (i.e. by blacklisting the amdgpu driver). I could accept better support for that GPU through the open source drivers, though - but as a choice.

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 80a8
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 130
    Memory at 91000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 5000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [100] #1b
    Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
    Capabilities: [300] #13
    Kernel driver in use: i915

01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265] (rev 81)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 80a8
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 11
    Memory at 80000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [disabled] [size=256M]
    Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [disabled] [size=2M]
    I/O ports at 4000 [disabled] [size=256]
    Memory at 92300000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=256K]
    Expansion ROM at 92340000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [150] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [270] #19
    Capabilities: [2b0] Address Translation Service (ATS)
    Capabilities: [2c0] #13
    Capabilities: [2d0] #1b
```

glxinfo tells me

```
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.4, 256 bits)
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 10.1.3
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
```

and when I try to run a Qt5 application:

```
libGL error: pci id for fd 13: 8086:1916, driver (null)
i965_dri.so does not support the 0x1916 PCI ID.
libGL error: failed to create dri screen
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
```

When I remove the amdgpu blacklist all that seems to change is that lspci now shows this:

```
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265] (rev 81)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 80a8
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 132
    Memory at 80000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=2M]
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=256]
    Memory at 92300000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Expansion ROM at 92340000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [150] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [270] #19
    Capabilities: [2b0] Address Translation Service (ATS)
    Capabilities: [2c0] #13
    Capabilities: [2d0] #1b
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
```

I did a quick scan of the kernel sources: I think I'm seeing references to i965 in the Intel driver sources but googling shows that i965 is apparently related to the AMD gpu? People apparently solved error messages about that driver not being found by reinstalling fglrx (which I don't have installed at all).

I'd prefer not to use the proprietary driver, at least not if that would oblige me to use an Xorg.conf file that will make it impractical to boot other hardware with the same external disk.

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I got quite a bit further after I noticed that there are xorg-*-lts-* packages, and a bit of googling led me to Ubuntu's page on LTS Enablement Stacks (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack).

I just needed to do

sudo apt-get install --install-recommends xserver-xorg-core-lts-wily xserver-xorg-lts-wily xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-wily xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-wily libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-wily

that's the command shown on the linked page minus the request to install a lts-wily kernel. I got one after all. Pity that there are no lts-xenial packages for XOrg but this  seems to work just fine too.

XOrg now opts to use the HD520 graphics, probably because support for the R7 is incomplete. IOW, the question about switchable graphics is still open but at least now I have a decent form of HW acceleration.
NB: I had to use the override settings in chrome://flags to get Google Chrome to use accelerated video playback, scrolling etc. I presume it'll be the same with Chromium.